# Azure Event Hub 5.6.0 - How to send an event to a specific partition id Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-eventhub

I was using azure/event-hubs 1.0.8 version in nodejs for sending the data to a specific partition id. Below is the sample code

[image]

Please could someone help me how to send data to event to a specific partition id using azure/event-hubs 5.6.0 version in nodejs?. I research a lot but couldn't find any source. Any help would be appreciated!

Below is the code for EventHub 5.6.0

```
 const insertOneInPartition = (data, partition, eventsHub) => {
  const dataToInsert = { body: { ...data } };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    eventsHub.createBatch({ partitionId : partition }).then(async eventDataBatch => {
      if (data) {
        eventDataBatch.tryAdd(dataToInsert);
        await eventsHub.sendBatch(eventDataBatch);
        resolve(eventsHub);
      } else {
        // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-promise-reject-errors
        reject('error');
      }
    }).catch(error => {
      reject(error);
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `nodejs` clients, see the `createBatch()` that takes an options argument that can contain either the partitionId or partition Key, see the sendEvents sample code at [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/37ee4bda47a099440206b1e76040d8bb89ca96c3/sdk/eventhub/event-hubs/samples/v5/browser/src/sendEvents.js), see line 41. You can use this browser app to send test messages to your specific partition.

For `Javascript` clients, you should pass the `partition ID` when creating the batch. frame the batchOptions with partition id and send it to `create_batch`(batchOptions), see line 35 for setting partitionId in code sample at https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/event-hubs/samples/v5/javascript/sendEvents.js

Comment: I have added my sample code for EventHub 5.6.0 in description. Please could you take it and edit it

Comment: see line 41 to know how to pass partitionId when you send message, https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/37ee4bda47a099440206b1e76040d8bb89ca96c3/sdk/eventhub/event-hubs/samples/v5/browser/src/sendEvents.js#L41

Comment: Understood I have edited my sample code in question description. That's right na?